# iOS infinite scroll items disapearing (sometimes)

Tags: ios, scroll, infinite

This is a very rare occurring bug from hell,

I have an infinite scroll controller that displays products, 2 in each row. Rarely, something affects the controller and causes items to vanish, when I tap the empty area where the item should be, it works as expected and directs the user to the item details controller. When I back out back to the list, sometimes the cell shows its content, and others get hidden.

Sometimes it just a couple of items missing, sometimes there are so many missing items that makes the list appear empty, like only 1 or 2 cells are visible per screen height.

An even stranger situation is, when I scroll really fast to the end and stretch the screen really fast out of the visible area, and there are no more items to load, the visible items can jump from left to right.

Please see these two videos.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jibflcouz1ena8n/missingProductImages.mov?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz13fzorypnp38t/again.mov?dl=0

I could send code but I didn't want to clutter this place with full length code, let me know if you want to see a specific section of the code please. Maybe someone could have an idea of what might be going on by looking at the vids.

Comment: Are you using `UICollectionView`? if yes, did you use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` too?

Comment: Yes `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout;
    
    CGFloat cellWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds) - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing) / 2;
    
    return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth + 72.f);  // 72.f is info lebels height
}`

Comment: I am not sure but I should add, I think this issue happens if something else goes wrong at another location and I come back here. Last time it happened I had a problem uploading images, received and error from the server, when I backed out of that part back to this listing page, things were as they are in the attached movies. This may be a one time thing but probably worth telling...

Comment: I "think" problem be from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I had the same problem, if my collectionView had more than two pages amount of cells, if i reached at the bottom of collectionView, all cells would disappear, and after that not a single delegate method would get called! I removed `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably going on here is a state problem with your collection view cells. The code assigning model values to the cell's views would be of use here. But absent any actual information, the first thing to review would be the cell's `prepareForReuse` implementation:

- Does it call super?
- Does it clear out all current values?
- Does it cancel any pending asynchronous operations?
- Are fetches and cancellations correctly matched?

Next, check if there's any essential configuration in the cell's `init`/`initWithCoder` methods -- those are only called on first creation, not on reuse.

Those are the normal pitfalls of UICollectionView cell handling. If they don't suggest the problem, please post the cell code.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I'll paste this here (entire controller code) while I check your suggestions, http://pastebin.com/bAGUjVFG

Comment: Looks suspiciously like some of those callbacks that provide the data might not be properly thread confined. If any UIKit calls are being made off the main thread, glitches and outright crashes are probable. I'd recommend applying [this gist here](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345) which should smoke out any problems of that sort.

Comment: Thanks, that was very valuable advise! This gist has caught something on somewhere else in the app. I am not sure if it is related at all to the controller in question...I am still testing and trying hard to reproduce, damn thing happens so rare.. I will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cells are not being reused correctly.

Can you check that you have set the same reuseIdentifier for your cell in Interface Builder that you are assigning in your code?

**Update**: Attached image to show where to set the identifier in the storyboard/xib

[image: Select your cell and enter the collection reusable view identifier]

**Update**: added layout solution

Another problem could be due to the layout bounds of your collectionViewCell. When you load your cells they bounds are not calculated until they have been added to your collectionView and rendered. This can cause the elements in your cell to layout with the wrong values. This happens commonly with async image frameworks as they cache a resized version of the image for performance. When you cell loads, the cached image is loaded at the wrong the wrong size.

Add the following code to your collectionViewCell:

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];
    self.contentView.frame = bounds;
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

Comment: I do it like this. `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FSCollectionViewProductCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([FSCollectionViewProductCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
    FSProductObject *product = indexPath.item < self.products.count ? self.products[indexPath.item] : nil;
    [cell configureCellWithProduct:product];
    
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    
    return cell;
}`

Comment: You need to ensure that you set the reuse identifier in your xib file to FSCollectionViewProductCell. See updated answer for screenshot

Comment: Hello, I confirm it is correct, same as your screenshot. May I add, this bug is happening about 2 times a week per phone on a full testing cycle. It is very rare.

Comment: Can I ask how you are loading your images? Are you using any async loading frameworks such as haneke?

Comment: if you mean images only, they are all setImageWithURL..     `[self.productImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL imageURLWithUDID:productObject.picture1GUID imageType:FSImageURLTypeProductList]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"productimageplaceholder"]];`

Comment: I seems that you are using AFNetorking's image loading stuff. I have update my answer for another possible solution regarding auto layout.